# How do I access the nth element in an ruby array? Specifically, a will_paginate collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, pagination

I am using ruby on rails and will_paginate to output posts to a page like this:

```
 <div class="posts">
        <% render @posts %>
 </div>
```

Let's say I want to change this page so that I render some posts in different divs:
     
     
            <% render 'posts/post', :post => #the first element in the collection %>

```
 <div class="second_post">
        <% render 'posts/post', :post => #the second element in the collection %>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class ="lower_container">
 <div class="posts">
        #may have to run a loop for this last one, to render all the rest of posts. How?
        <% render 'posts/post', :post => #all other posts %>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Specifically, I know I could use @post.first for the first element, but don't know about  the second (or third, or fourth elements). Naturally, my programming background makes me want to do @post(n) where n is the index of the element I want to access. This doesn't work in ruby.

FYI: The post collection is created in the controller by:

```
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Does anyone know how I would best accomplish this goal? I know it may seem unconventional, but for the html/UI aspects I really want to do have the divs like this..

Comment: I know there's a little-known feature in rails for rendering a collection into multiple columns but my google-fu is failing me

Answer (score 0):

Inside your partial you can call:

```
<%= posts_counter %>
```

Or `<partial_name>_counter`

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3's nth-child selectors to target specific div's. For example, if your code looked like:

```
<div id="posts">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div>
    <%= post.content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Then you can target the first and second `<div>` like this:

```
div#posts div:nth-child(1) { }
div#posts div:nth-child(2) { }
```

jQuery also can select them the same way, and add the classes to them if you require it:

```
$('div#posts div:nth-child(1)').addClass('firstPost');
```

**Update:**

Okay, after your response I'd suggest using the each_with_index helper method when iterating through your collection, like so:

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <% if index == 0 %>
    <div class="specialFirstIndexClass">
      <%= post.content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if index == 1 %>
    <div class="specialSecondIndexClass">
      <%= post.content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or you could use a Ruby switch like so, as they're pretty:

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <% case index %>
  <% when 0 %>
    <div class="specialFirstIndexClass">
      <%= post.content %>
    </div>
  <% when 1 %>
    #etc..
  <% else %>
    <div class="notSoSpecial"><%= post.content %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this won't suffice - I want to put the divs in different container-divs themselves, so it's not suffice just to change their properties (i'll edit the question). With that in mind, any ideas?

Comment: @geb2011: Hey I updated my answer, I think `each_with_index` is what you're after.